# Почему при пустом вводе данных от пользователя, всё равно в списке что-то появляется?

Tags: python, list, input

```
list_1 = []
print(list_1)
list_1.append(input())
print(list_1)
```

Почему, если при требовании ввести данные просто нажать интер (без внесения прочих символов), всё равно образуется пустой элемент в списке?

Comment: Пользователь ввёл пустую строку. Пустая строка попала в список. Что тут необычного?

Comment: Списку неважно, что хранить. Скажут добавить пустую строку - добавит. Скажут добавить None - тоже добавит. Каждый append добавляет новый элемент в список.

Answer (score 3):

Код просто добавил пустую строку в список, как уже говорили, что списку без разницы что хранить, хоть даже и пустую строку.

Comment: +1 голос, но вы все-таки за речью следите.

Comment: @Глеб, хорошо, буду следить

Answer (score 2):

Вот один из способов избежать такого поведения:
Мы сохраняем данные, введенные пользователем в переменную user_input. Затем проверяем его булево значение, и если строка не пустая(то есть значение user_input будет True), добавляем ее в список.

```
list_1 = []
print(list_1)
user_input = input()
if user_input:
    list_1.append(user_input)
print(list_1)
```